# SharePoint Absolute Reference - Fixed Value in Calculated Field

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm looking for a way to get the absolute reference of a specific "cells" in a SharePoint calculated column ?

For example I got this SharePoint list:

A1 - B1 - C1

A2 - B2 - C2

My calculated field should be = [B1] x [C]

It is like the $B$1 on Excel.

I did not find any kind of answers on my searches.

Is there something that I miss? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so this is possible OOTB. The calculate columns works only on particular item that too only when you create an item or modify item. So in simple words, this is not possible OOTB.